# How do I access ALL selenium functionality from Javascript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber

Selenium functionality is not available in Javascript/Typescript as declared. I need to be able to access all selenium functionality.

In C#/Visual Studio, I could do this:

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;


public string GetSelectedComboItem(IWebDriver _driver, string strLocator)
{
    string strOption = "";

    try
    {            
        IWebElement _combobox = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='" + strLocator + "']"));
        SelectElement comboitem = new SelectElement(_combobox);
        strOption = comboitem.SelectedOption.Text;
        return strOption;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return strOption;
    }
}
```

This works nicely. In TypeScript, I'm working with definitions like this in World.ts:

```
import { WebDriver, Builder, Capabilities, Options } from 'selenium-webdriver';
```

The problem is that I can't seem to access the same functionality in TypeScript that I could in C#. VSCode Autocomplete gives me nothing. Options like `SelectedOption` seem completely unavailable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is missing functionality, or just missing IDE friendly documentation?

Comment: :) Probably the latter. I'm now going through the webdriver-Selenium index.js file to figure it out. Coming from C#, it's a whole new world.